# Displaying a page preview and manipulate it in another site

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I'd like to show the user a small preview of another page (from a different domain) and let him control the page's elements. For example: replace the logo on the top.

I tried two approaches:

1. Using an iFrame causes me cross domain issues.
2. I can't "preinstall" javascript functions on that page either.

Would love to get more ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: what do u mean by control??? Do u want user to edit another domain's page html on the fly???

Comment: @Sandeep, what I want to do is a preview pane where the user will be able to see how his actions in the admin interface will affect the real page. I don't want to copy the page because if the source changes, I will have to change on my end too.

Comment: So for this rather showing page from other domain. just have a clone on the page (check jsfiddle/jsbin for examples) and the changes done in admin interface should get reflected in the cloned region.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how that can solve the problem. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to http://jsbin.com/

The output div has a iframe where your page cloned from other domain.

On the other hand you should have your admin interface where user changes anything change the HTML of the iframe content (as it is a clone not directly from other domain browser allows you to modify). So a live preview can be shown to user.

Here, for how to change the iframe HTML u have many examples otherwise refer to the jsbin.com code.

I just came across this article. This might help you. http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-safeguard-your-site-with-html5-sandbox/